# Buld a angular2 webpack production project without source code on the dist folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, production

I am working on a web application using angular 2 with typescript and angular-cli. I wanted to make a test on the server but I didn't want to upload the source code then I tried using the command "ng build --prod". I see that the .map files was on the folder yet and I deleted all .map files and I uploaded the folder on the server, When I opened the dev tool on chrome I saw the source code with TypeScript. The files that I didn't delete were the .gz files. My question is What is the correct way to build a production project without the typescript code with webpack?.

Sorry but I don't speak english well. And I don't know if I am describing in the corret way my dude.

What I want is not to show my TypeScript code for anyone that activate developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by, "build a production project without the typescript code".

When you build a project with `ng build` it compiles all the typescript into js and minifies it. For example, here is the output of ng build for me (note there are no typescript files here):

[image]

As you noted you can also use the -prod which sets the environment production value to true and gives you a slightly smaller, more optimized build. If you just want to test you app in the browser you can use `ng serve` or `ng serve -prod`.